How to choose between standard post bases and high-uplift-resistance post bases for deck?
I designed a 12'x16', 16" high deck using Simpson Strong-Tie Deck Planner Software. I'll be using Trex 1" deck boards with 3/16" spacing.
The software specified Simpson ABU post bases to tie the beam directly to the concrete footings, without posts. Compared to the cheaper ABA-series bases, the ABU series is rated to resist around ~3.5x as much uplift force, at around twice the cost. I haven't found any specific estimates or requirements of how much uplift force my deck needs to resist, in the local building code or elsewhere. What I have found is that lower decks will typically experience less uplift force than taller decks, but no specific numbers.
How can I determine if the cheaper ABA-series post bases are sufficient for my deck?

What wind do you have?  Does the deck have spaces between the floor boards or is it solid?

The deck will have 3/16" spacing between boards. I'm located in Seattle, which appears to have a wind design speed of 105 mph, according to the 2018 Washington building code I found at https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/WABC2018P2/chapter-16-structural-design

With a 105 mph wind and only 3/16 spacing, maybe the high lift mounts is a good idea.  Local code should say which mounts are allowed/needed.  Your local building inspector should be able to tell you what they allow.  A low deck with a solid skirt instead of being open might matter.

Ask you local building department.  I believe the ABA series bases will serve you fine.  The winds are measured a a certain height and you will not get the same velocity so close to ground level.

If you spec the ABA series in your plans and the plans get rejected when applying for the permit, you know you'll need the ABU series. Or, just ask before submitting the plans...

In my jurisdiction, decks under 30" high are exempt from permitting, so I wasn't planning on submitting plans.

It does sound like asking the building department is a great idea, so I'll try that.
